# Python challenge - rows and columns count

Tags: python, count, rows

I'm working on a challenge which basically consist on assigning to a set of rows and columns on a table, a value by a function in python. In this case the character's value to be placed on a specific position on the talbe is the "#". I have been able to make it work, but as you will se on the ouput is that the top which represent the columns list is not totally aligned (top right hand side) to the row line. On the attached screen shot you'll see a more detailed description.

Below is the code I am using where I'have been able to get this far.

```
def bucle_for1(lista):
    x = 0
    
    for i in lista:
        if x <= 9:
            print(x,"", i)
        else:
             print(x, i)
        x += 1

def crear_mundo(d):
    mundo = []
    columna = []
    
    for x in range(d):
        for x in range(d):
            if x <= 9:
                columna.append(" ")
                if x >= 10:
                    columna.append("")
                else:
                    columna.append(" ")
            else:
                columna.append("")
        mundo.append(columna)
        columna = []
    return mundo

def crear_listadocolumnas(d):
    listadocolumnas = []
    for x in range(d):
        listadocolumnas.append(str(x))      
    return listadocolumnas

def muros(mundo):
    muros = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[2,2],
            [3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],
            [3,8],[3,9],[3,10],[3,11],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],
            [4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[4,10],
            [4,11],[5,11],[6,11],[6,11],[6,12],[6,13],
            [6,14],[6,15]]
    for x in range(len(muros)):
        f = muros [x][0]
        c = muros [x][1]
        mundo [f][c] = "#"
    return mundo

mundo = crear_mundo(32)
print("  ", crear_listadocolumnas(32))
bucle_for1(muros(mundo))
```

[image: Code output]

I'm now where I wanted to be with the code (thanks to Display name). Now, I was wodering if you could help me on how to look for the width and len of the following according to the same output. What function should I use so I can calculate the width of column 1 and 2 and also to know the len of the same columns 1 and 2?

Comment: Please put the details in the text, not in hard-to-read text in the screenshot.

Comment: Pro tip: Use `for x, i in enumerate(lista):` to get the index and element, instead of incrementing the `x` variable yourself.

Comment: You shouldn't nest two loops that both use `x` as the iteration variable.

Comment: `if x >= 10:` will never be true, because it's inside the `if x <= 9:` block.

Comment: Put `columna = []` at the beginning of the outer loop, so you don't have to repeat it before the loop and at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Even after reading the details in the screenshot, I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for? Basically, if x is greater than 9 (I.E. 2 characters long, I add

```
    def bucle_for1(lista):
    x = 0

    for i in lista:
        if x <= 9:
            print(x,"", i)
        else:
            print(x, i)
        x += 1



def crear_mundo(d):
    mundo = []
    columna = []
    for x in range(d):
        for x in range(d):
            if x <= 9:
                columna.append(" ")
                if x >= 10:
                    columna.append("")
                else:
                    columna.append(" ")
            else:
                columna.append("")
            if x>9:
                columna[x] = "  "
        mundo.append(columna)
        columna = []
    return mundo



def crear_listadocolumnas(d):
    listadocolumnas = []
    for x in range(d):
        listadocolumnas.append(str(x))
    return listadocolumnas


def muros(mundo):
    muros = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[2,2],
             [3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],
             [3,8],[3,9],[3,10],[3,11],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],
             [4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[4,10],
             [4,11],[5,11],[6,11],[6,11],[6,12],[6,13],
             [6,14],[6,15]]
    for x in range(len(muros)):
        f = muros [x][0]
        c = muros [x][1]
        mundo [f][c] = "#"
        if c>9:
            mundo[f][c] += " "
    return mundo

mundo = crear_mundo(32)
print("  ", crear_listadocolumnas(32))
bucle_for1(muros(mundo))
```

**Add single white space after column 31**
You can also use this code if you want lines beyond 31 to be a single white space instead of an empty string.

```
def crear_mundo(d):
    mundo = []
    columna = []
    for x in range(d):
        for x in range(d):
            if x <= 9:
                columna.append(" ")
                if x >= 10:
                    columna.append("")
                else:
                    columna.append(" ")
            else:
                columna.append(" ")
            if x>9:
                columna[x] += " "
        mundo.append(columna)
        columna = []
    return mundo

def muros(mundo):
        muros = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[2,2],
                 [3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],
                 [3,8],[3,9],[3,10],[3,11],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],
                 [4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[4,10],
                 [4,11],[5,11],[6,11],[6,11],[6,12],[6,13],
                 [6,14],[6,15]]
        for x in range(len(muros)):
            f = muros [x][0]
            c = muros [x][1]
            mundo [f][c] = "#"
            if c>9:
                mundo[f][c] += " "
        return mundo
```

[image: Example of code]

**To Match the column length, use this:**

```
def bucle_for1(lista):
    x = 0

    for i in lista:
        if x <= 9:
            print(x,"", i)
        else:
            print(x, i)
        x += 1



def crear_mundo(d):
    mundo = []
    columna = []
    for x in range(d):
        for x in range(d):
            if x <= 9:
                columna.append(" ")
                if x >= 10:
                    columna.append("")
            else:
                columna.append(" ")
            if x>9:
                columna[x] += " "
        mundo.append(columna)
        columna = []
    return mundo



def crear_listadocolumnas(d):
    listadocolumnas = []
    for x in range(d):
        listadocolumnas.append(str(x))
    return listadocolumnas


def muros(mundo):
    muros = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[2,2],
             [3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],
             [3,8],[3,9],[3,10],[3,11],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],
             [4,4],[4,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9],[4,10],
             [4,11],[5,11],[6,11],[6,11],[6,12],[6,13],
             [6,14],[6,15]]
    for x in range(len(muros)):
        f = muros [x][0]
        c = muros [x][1]
        mundo [f][c] = "#"
        if c>9:
            mundo[f][c] += " "
    return mundo

mundo = crear_mundo(32)
print("  ", crear_listadocolumnas(32))
bucle_for1(muros(mundo))
```

**Example:**
[image: An Example of matched width]

**Get character length of the printed rows**

```
def bucle_for1(lista):
    x = 0

    for i in lista:
        y=0
        if x <= 9: y=1
        print(len(str(str(x)+""+ str(i))) + (y))
        if x <= 9:
            print(x,"", i)
        else:
            print(x, i)
        x += 1
```

Comment: That approach seems to be more what I was looking for. But, how do I get the columns after 31 on the top top to be aligned with the rest of the matrix. That would be like 10 single white spaces.

Comment: To have every line after column 31 to have a single white space, then please look at the second part of my post. 

You would just replace the crear_mundo function from the main code with the crear_mundo function that is below it.

I will highlight this section to help you see it.

Comment: I have modified that line of code as highlighted on the screen shot, and as you can I almost got it to align to the right the top row, but still is not 100% there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this new line of code work? Also, I realized that I left out a change that I added. That has been added in the second section of code.

Comment: Outstanding mate. you got it. It's amazing what you can do with python when you know where to look. I'm just a beginner so hopefully with a lot of practice and studying I'll get to your level.

Comment: If my answer answered your question, I would appreciate it if you can mark it as the correct answer. 

I am pretty basic in Python too, I've been taking online bootcamps to teach myself.

Comment: Now, I was wodering if you could help me on how to look for the width and len of the following according to the same output. What function should I use so I can calculate the width of column 1 and 2 and also to know the len of the same columns 1  and 2?

Comment: Could you make a new question for that?

Comment: Sorry, I though the way I riased the question was the correct one. Obviously it wasn't. I just deleted that part.

Comment: This has the same problem as the OP of using the same variable `x` in both nested loops. If the outer loop's iteration variable isn't needed, use `for _`

Comment: @Barmar I tried to keep the code as vanilla as possible. The last thing I want is to rewrite someone else's code. Also, using x twice still worked so there's no need to change it.

Comment: @CC I just added a bit of code to change the bucle_for1 method to print the number of characters in each row. Is that what you were looking for? If you want the length of the array, then you can just do len(mundo) or len(mundo[0])